# php mysql group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

this is my table

```
 row  | car_id | car_model | car_features |
  1      1          CAR 1      Features 1
  2      2          CAR 2      Features 2
  3      2          CAR 2      Features 3
```

and i want to make it like

```
 row  | car_id | car_model | car_features |
  1      1          CAR 1      Features 1
  2      2          CAR 2      Features 2, Features 3
```

and this is my php mysql script:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysql_select_db("car", $con);
    $format = mysql_query("SELECT c.* , p.*, d.*,f.* ,e.* FROM bsi_car_master c,bsi_car_type p, bsi_car_vendor d, bsi_selected_features f, bsi_car_features e WHERE c.car_type_id=p.id AND c.car_vendor_id=d.id AND c.car_id = f.car_id AND f.features_id = e.id");
    $row = 1;

    while($srow = mysql_fetch_array($format))
    {
        blah blah blah....
    }
?>
```

Comment: can show me some example ... :)

Comment: Aw, don't use group concat. Just modify your loop.

Comment: @Strawberry can give me some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`. Try this -

```
SELECT `row`, `car_id`, `car_model`, GROUP_CONCAT(`car_features`, ',') 
FROM your_table GROUP BY `car_id`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT car_id,car_model,GROUP_CONCAT(car_features,',')  
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY car_id,car_model;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$format = mysql_query("SELECT c.* , p.*, d.*,f.* ,e.*,group_concat(`c.car_features`,',') as `carfeatures` FROM bsi_car_master c,bsi_car_type p, bsi_car_vendor d, bsi_selected_features f, bsi_car_features e WHERE c.car_type_id=p.id AND c.car_vendor_id=d.id AND c.car_id = f.car_id AND f.features_id = e.id group by c.car_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, it's fairly obvious that I'm no PHP coder, but here's another way to do it, without GROUP_CONCAT()...

```
<?php
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,car_id INT NOT NULL
,car_model VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,car_features VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1      ,1          ,'CAR 1','Features 1'),
(2      ,2          ,'CAR 2','Features 2'),
(3      ,2          ,'CAR 2','Features 3');
*/

require('path/to/mysqli/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
    SELECT id
         , car_id
         , car_model
         , car_features
      FROM my_table
     ORDER
        BY car_model;
    ";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
 $car_id = 0;

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if ($car_id== $row['car_id']){
 echo  "  >".$row['car_features']."<br>\n";
 } else {
 echo $row['car_model']."<br>\n  >".$row['car_features']."<br>\n";
$car_id = $row['car_id'];
 }
 } // end of while loop

/* 
Outputs...

CAR 1
>Features 1
CAR 2
>Features 2
>Features 3
*/

?>
```